# Lost in interface variance. IInterface<in T1, out T2> is not working as expected

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, variance

Hi, I have a variant factory interface. Now, I am deriving factories from it and would like to be able to pass a factory of more derived type as a factory of less derived type. It doesn't work and I am really trying to figure out why as from the little I know about variance, it should.

Please consider this code:

```
public interface IFactory<in TParam, out TValue> { }

public class Fruit { }

public class Apple : Fruit { }

public class BoxOfFruits { }

public class BoxOfApples : BoxOfFruits { }

public class BoxOfFruitsFactory : IFactory<Fruit, BoxOfFruits> { }

public class BoxOfApplesFactory : IFactory<Apple, BoxOfApples> { }

public class FruitPacker
{
    public FruitPacker(IFactory<Fruit, BoxOfFruits> factory) { }
}

public class ApplePacker : FruitPacker
{
    //This works fine as expected, as there is no variance in play.
    public ApplePacker(BoxOfFruitsFactory factory) : base(factory) { }

    //This complains about not being able to convert BoxOfApplesFactory to IFactory<Fruit, BoxOfFruits>
    public ApplePacker(BoxOfApplesFactory factory) : base(factory) { }

    //This is not working either
    public ApplePacker(IFactory<Apple, BoxOfApples> factory) : base(factory) { }

    //But this does work
    public ApplePacker(IFactory<Fruit, BoxOfApples> factory) : base(factory) { }
}
```

Could someone please explain, why this is not working? My assumtions are that "in" lets me pass in more derived type and "out" lets me output less derived type.

Thanks

Comment: '"in" lets me pass in more derived type'. Indeed it does. So you have something that, at the very least, needs to be passed an `Apple` and you're trying to pass it to something that wants to be able to supply any `Fruit`.

Comment: Oh, sure, dammit. Thanks, that is of course correct. Could you make it into an answer so I can accept it?